# Detecting When A Moving Shape Is Clicked (For A Game)

Tags: animation, arraylist, javafx, click

I'm a CS scrub and I thought I understood everything until now. I'm being prompted to make anything I want, so I'm choosing to make a little game I've been thinking about for a few months.  The problem is that I don't know where to start. We've been using JavaFX and we've done some animation but I don't fully understand everything. I don't really understand mouse events but the idea I have depends on them. Anyway, here's the idea:

The main (2D) game is about reducing fractions.

Imagine the window being split horizontally into top and bottom.
Now, imagine boxes spawning out of view and moving into view toward the horizontal center line. The boxes will only be moving vertically and each box has a random integer. When a box gets to the center, it'll stay there and allow for other boxes to land on top of it (or below it if it came from the bottom).

Boxes are eliminated by "reducing" a number in the numerator with a number in the denominator. Several boxes may be selected on one side before reducing them with the other side. Here's a picture that might help convey what I want to do:
  [Crude Three Frames of the Gameplay Drawn In Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJENS.png)

Hopefully that all makes sense.
I've been trying to use an extension of Rectangle but I don't really know what else to do. I figure I'll need to create some ArrayLists to keep track of the boxes and some other lists to keep track of factors as well. Anyway, any help would be fantastic. Thank you guys very much!

Comment: Add the listener to your root/scene. Then get the event target. I think this should work. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: I figured something out some 10 hours after I posted this! For the first draft of the code, I made some Text and Rectangle objects and put them on a stack pane. Then I animated everything by changing the layoutX and layoutY relative to the root Pane. I setOnMouseClick the StackPane from there. Thank you very much though, I'm glad to know I'm in the right direction! :D